# Possible new theorem in plane geometry encompassing 5 famous geometry theorems

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

I am looking for a proof of a generalization Napoleon theorem, Bottema theorem and Brahmagupta theorem and van Aubel theorem, and Finsler–Hadwiger theorem in one configuration, as follows:

Let four points $A, B, C, D$ in the plain, the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ meets the perpendicular bisector of $CD$ at $P$. then always exist only one point $S$ such that:

1. $(\overrightarrow{\rm PD}, \overrightarrow{\rm PC})\equiv 2(AD, AS) \equiv 2(BS, BC)$ and $(\overrightarrow{\rm PB}, \overrightarrow{\rm PA})\equiv 2(CB, CS) \equiv 2(DS, DA)$ (in the figure).
2. The line through $S$ meets the perpendicular bisector of $CD$ at $E$ then $ES \perp AB$ if only if $(\overrightarrow{\rm EC}, \overrightarrow{\rm ED})\equiv 2(SC, SB) \equiv 2(SA, SD)$

[image]

**Application:**

If the problem was proved. Then we can apply the theorem to proof two famous theorem:

1. A Proof of the [Napoleon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem): Apply the theorem part one with $\beta=120^\circ$ and $\alpha=30^\circ$ (See Figure 1).
2. A Proof of the [Bottema theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottema%27s_theorem): Apply the theorem part one with $\beta=45^\circ$ and $\alpha=90^\circ$ (See Figure 1).
3. A proof of [Van Aubel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel%27s_theorem). Apply the theorem part one, with $\alpha=\gamma=45^\circ$
4. A roof of [Finsler–Hadwiger theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler%E2%80%93Hadwiger_theorem). Apply the theorem part one, with $\alpha=\gamma=45^\circ$
5. A Proof of the [Brahmagupta theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula): Apply the theorem part two with $\gamma=90^\circ$ (See Figure 1).

**See also:**

- [Relative a generalization Bottema theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q3h557966p3244119)

Comment: In (2): which line through $S$ do you mean? Just some? Also, on your picture you take intersection of this line with the perpendicular bisector of $CD$, while in the condition you speak about perpendicular bisector of $AB$

Comment: I am sory, I correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be a circumcentre of $\triangle ADS$. Then $\triangle OAS \sim \triangle PAB$, thus $\triangle POA\sim \triangle BSA$ and $BS:PO=SA:OA$, $\angle (BS,PO)=\angle (SA,OA)$. Analogously $CS:PO=SD:OD$ and $\angle (CS,PO)=\angle (SD,OD)$. This gives that $BS:CS=SA:SD$ and by angle chasing $\angle BSC=\gamma$, so $\triangle BSC\sim \triangle ASD$ (with different orientation), and we get the first part of your question.

Now let $K$ by symmetric to $C$ with respect to line $BS$. Let $E$ be a point such that $\triangle CED\sim \triangle CSK$, so that $E$ lies on the perpendicular bisector to $CD$ and $\angle CED=2\gamma$. We need to prove that $SE\perp AB$. We get $\triangle CES\sim \triangle CDK$, thus $\angle (ES,DK)=\angle (CE,CD)=\pi/2-\gamma$. But $\triangle DSK\sim \triangle ASB$, thus $\angle (DK,AB)=\angle (DS,AS)=\gamma$, and $\angle (ES,AB)=\angle (ES,DK)+\angle (DK,AB)=\pi/2$.

Comment: Mister @FedorPetrov Is the proof complete?

Comment: I think so, why not?